# how to read the response json data from the server in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I am new to Sencha and working on reading the response JSON data from the server and displaying in an alert, but on response, handleSuccess function is getting executed and getting the data in the alert to be as undefined. So I want Message data in JSON to be displayed in the alert. Thanks for any kind of help.

JSON data from server:

**{"data":[{"Success":"FALSE","Message":"Data to be loaded","groupCount":0,"maxSeverity":10}]}**

```
Ext.Ajax.request({

    url: 'serverurl',

    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },

    params: {

        username: 'username',

        password: 'password'
    },

    method: 'GET',

    success: handleSuccess,

    failure: handleError

});




  function handleSuccess( response, opts )

{

  var jsonData = Ext.decode(response.Message);

   alert(jsonData)

}

function handleError( response, opts )

{

   alert('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, use response.responseText for retrieving the json object

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({ 
    url: URL,
    defaultHeaders : 'application/json', 

    success : function(response, opt) {
       // this will give you the JSON       
       Ext.Msg.alert('Success', response.responseText); 
    },

    failure : function(response, opt) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', response.responseText); 
    }   
 });
```

This works for me, it should work for your too.